# Construct a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, pointwise-convergence

Let $a_n$ be a given sequence of numbers (constant), $X$ be a standard normal random variable. Construct a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n \rightarrow X \text{ a.s.}$ and $E(X_n) = a_n$ for all $n$.

I understand that this essentially tells us why dominated-ness is needed in DCT. Now, I tried to construct $X_n$ such that for any $\epsilon >0$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon) < \infty$ as this a sufficient condition for almost sure convergence. But, I don't really see how to complete the construction.

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: @Surb please look at the edits. I have tried to explain my thought process.  Sorry for not being clearer !

Comment: What is the simpliest example of sequence $(X_n)$ converging to $X$ almost surely (without assumption $\mathbb E[X_n] = a_n$)?

Comment: $X_n = X + b_n$ where $b_n \rightarrow 0$ is one that comes to mind

Comment: Yes, even sequence $X_n = X$ obviously converges a.s to $X$, but $\mathbb E[X_n] = 0$. Having said that, it is wise to consider $X_n = X + Y_n$, and try to find $(Y_n)$ such that $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely and $\mathbb E[Y_n]=a_n$. Hint: It should be non-zero only on a small (in the sense of probability) set.

Comment: Ok so we can define $Y_n = 2^n a_n \text{  w.p. } \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $0$ otherwise. This hopefully does the trick ! Can you please confirm @DominikKutek

Comment: Yes, that's exactly something I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dominik in the comments, we can define $X_n = X + 2^n a_n B_n$ where $B_n \sim Ber(\frac{1}{2^n})$. This concludes our construction.